# tf.estimator.Estimator not logging any event files, tensorboard showing nothing

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently running `TensorFlow 1.9.0`. My custom estimator is created with `tf.estimator.Estimator`, and run without a glitch. However, I don't find any event files under `model_dir`, and TensorBoard simply shows nothing.

Here's how I setup my estimator:

```
classifier= tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=lr_model_fn, model_dir=PATH)
```

and I open TensorBoard via `tensorboard --logdir=tf_models/ --host=127.0.0.1` where `tf_models` is the dir `PATH`.

Files logged in `model_dir` include `checkpoint`, `graph.pbtxt`, `model.ckpt-*`, etc. No `events.out.tfevents*` files reside there. Is this normal? Did I have something misconfigured?

Comment: I hope you started up Tensorboard on a separate terminal and pointed it to PATH.

Comment: @ coldspeed I simply run `tensorboard --logdir=tf_models/ --host=127.0.0.1` where `tf_models` is the dir `PATH`, on a separate terminal tab.

Comment: Try specifying the entire path. Also, make sure to pass a `--port=xxxx` argument so tensorboard knows what port to host on.

Comment: Just did an update to TF version 1.10.0, and the problem seems gone.

Comment: @coldspeed I find it super weird though that it only outputs `events.out.tfevents.*` file the very first time in a Jupyter session. If clean up the log dir and train the model whatever times afterwards, there's always a events file missing there. And I have to restart Jupyter to make it work again. Don't know if this is your case also, or an unsolved bug.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when you delete the previously defined `model_dir` in your `Estimator` configuration: `FileWriter` will fail to write in the deleted directory (even a directory with the same path is created).

You can use `tf.summary.FileWriterCache.clear()` to clear current cache if this happens. You will lose anterior cached summaries though.